# Solve the equation $4 \sin x \cos (2x) \sin (3x) = 1$ for $0^{\circ} < x < 180^{\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried using identities but none of them worked for me.

Eg: $4 \sin x(1 - 2 \sin^2 x)(3 \sin x - 4 \sin^3 x) = 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\cos{x}=0$ so $x=90^{\circ},$ which is not a root of the equation.

Thus, for $x\neq90^{\circ}$ our equation is equivalent to
$$4\cos{x}\sin{x}\cos2x\sin3x=\cos{x}$$  or
$$\sin4x\sin3x=\cos{x}$$ or
$$\cos{x}-\cos7x=2\cos{x}$$ or
$$\cos7x+\cos{x}=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: I don’t understand how the first statement ( “ If cos...”) implies “our equation is equivalent to...”. And why did you assume x = 0?

Comment: @Steve Harris I wrote it very bad. I fixed. See now.

Comment: Could you show how you reduced the equation to: sin 4x sin 3x = cos x?

Comment: To which equation?

Comment: How you went from 4 cos x sin x cos 2x sine 3 x = cos x to sin 4x sin 3x = 0

Comment: @Steve Harris I used $\sin2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$ twice: $2\sin{x}\cos{x}=\sin2x$ and $2\sin2x\cos2x=\sin4x$.

Comment: Excellent! A very helpful answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96958/discussion-between-steve-harris-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Make a *partial* linearisation: $\;2\sin x\sin 3x=\cos(3x-x)-\cos(3x+x)$, so 
\begin{align}
4 \sin x \cos (2x) \sin (3x)&=2\cos 2x(\cos 2x-\cos 4x)=2\cos^22x-2\cos 2x\cos 4x\\
&=1+\cos 4x-2\cos 2x\cos 4x,
\end{align}
and after simplification, the equation becomes
$$\cos 4x(1-2\cos 2x)=0.$$
Can you solve this one?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is 
$$4\sin(x)\cos(2x)\sin(3x)-1=$$$$-2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{4}-2 x\right) \sin \left(2
   x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) (2 \cos (2 x)-1)$$

Comment: Could you explain how you derived line two from line one?

Answer (score 1):

$$4 \sin(x)\cos(2x)\sin(3x) - 1 = 32 \sin(x)^6 - 40 \sin(x)^4 + 12 \sin(x)^2 - 1$$
Letting $\sin(x) = s$, this is 
$$ 32 s^6 - 40 s^4 + 12 s^2 - 1 = (2s+1)(2s-1)(8s^4 - 8s^2+1)$$
which has roots 
$$ s = \pm \frac{1}{2},\; \pm \frac{\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2}}}{2} $$
The values of $x$ in $(0,\pi)$ are $$\frac{\pi}{8},\; \frac{\pi}{6},\; \frac{3\pi}{8},\; \frac{5\pi}{8}\; \frac{5\pi}{6},\; \frac{7\pi}{8}$$
or in degrees, $$22.5,\; 30,\; 67.5,\; 112.5,\; 150,\; 157.5 $$